# rsync exclude file: correct syntax to exclude specific folders whose names include spaces

Tags: rsync

I'm having a hard time trying to exclude some folders whose names include spaces from a rsync command using the --exclude-from=excludefile.txt option.
So far I've tried:

```
"Spaces in Folder Name"
'Spaces in Folder Name'
Spaces in Folder Name


"(fullpath)/Spaces in Folder Name"
'(fullpath)/Spaces in Folder Name'
(fullpath)/Spaces in Folder Name

and

"./Spaces in Folder Name"
'./Spaces in Folder Name'
./Spaces in Folder Name
```

And none of this works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it right by using this syntax:

SPACES\ IN\ FOLDER\ NAME*

Paths are relative to 'destination_folder', spaces are escaped with a backslash, and an asterix must be mysteriously placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section called **ADVANCED USAGE** in the [`rsync` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) which says:

> ### ADVANCED USAGE
>
> Older versions of `rsync` required using quoted spaces in the `SRC`, like these examples:
>
> ```
> rsync -av host:'dir1/file1 dir2/file2' /dest
> rsync host::'modname/dir1/file1 modname/dir2/file2' /dest
> ```
>
> This word-splitting still works (by default) in the latest rsync, but is not as easy to use as the first method.
>
> If  you  need  to  transfer  a filename that contains whitespace, you can either specify the `--protect-args` (`-s`) option, or you’ll need to escape the whitespace in a way that the remote shell will understand.  For instance:
>
> ```
> rsync -av host:'file\ name\ with\ spaces' /dest
> ```

So I think you just need the to use the `-s` command line option.

The other method is to somehow add a backslash in the front of each space which I think is going to be much harder to do. Plus, if you do not need this advanced feature, then the `-s` is enough.

Further, the pattern is expected to include a slash and asterisk as in:

```
# Matches the folder itself
Spaces in Folder Name
# Matches the sub-files directly inside the folder
Spaces in Folder Name/*
# Matches any file at any level found under folder
Spaces in Folder Name/**

# Or: matches the folder and any file under folder
Spaces in Folder Name/***
```

So you are probably interested by the last one (note that it was introduced in version 2.6.7, so if you have an older version, the plain name + name with `/` and two `**` would work for you).

Comment: I've tried this but sorry it does not work. I'm using the --exclude-from=excludefile.txt option where excludefile.txt is a list of excluded items. I just cannot exclude folders like I exclude files or extensions.

Comment: @brunobhr Right. Your patterns are not sufficient. I've updated my answer. I think that you can use `Spaces in Folder Name/***` in your case.